# How to put a file upload button in a slide menu?

Tags: html, css, wordpress

I have a social network site through wordpress.  I would like to place a file upload button in the slide menu so users can open the slide menu and upload their  profile pics from there.  I am very new to this and have much to learn but the little I've learn to this point has really got me hooked. I just started using code to customize and would love to know the correct path to take on this matter.   Any help is very much appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

You can add a file upload form in your slide menu template code by

```
<form action="upload.php" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">
    Select image to upload:
    <input type="file" name="fileToUpload" id="fileToUpload">
    <input type="submit" value="Upload Image" name="submit">
</form>
```

and you can learn more [here](http://www.w3schools.com/php/php_file_upload.asp) it might help you understand it more.

Answer (score 0):

You need to best use of the following plugin here : [Frontend Uploader](https://wordpress.org/plugins/frontend-uploader/)

This will help you to embed the front Uploader where users can upload their profile picture/media content.

Users must have to register/login to site to upload the media files/profile picture.